How to win 'The Simple Loop Game'?
There is a pencil puzzle type called 'Simple Loop'. In short, you need to draw exactly one loop passing all white cells on the board exactly once. A more detailed version of the rules can be viewed at here.
One day, some of my friends invented a game about it:

Start from a 10x10 board (more generally, rectangular grid of even size and side lengths at least 2) with all cells white
Two players take turns coloring 2 cells black
Game ends when this board viewed as a Simple Loop puzzle has no solution, the player colored the last 2 cells loses

They call it 'The Simple Loop Game'.
Obviously, this is a finite game. As there are no draws, one of the players has a winning strategy. Who has the winning strategy and what is it?

the players take turns coloring cells black one at a time or two at a time? if it is two at a time, do the two cells need to be connected in anyway?

The two black cells are colored at the same time and don't need to be adjacent.

Begin by coloring the two squares adjacent to a corner black. Then there can be no loop trough the isolated white square in the corner. Why does this not win?

@Patrik Because the player who colored the last 2 cells loses, so you've found a losing strategy.

This is too hard of a problem to be asked on MSE.

Extended comment: The board can be understood as grid graph of size $2n$ by $2n$. The players take turn by excising vertices two at a time. We move to progressively smaller subgraphs and the game is done when the graph in question does not admit a "a simple loop solution" -- this is equivalent to saying that the subgraph does not have a Hamiltonian cycle.
For reference, the question "does this grid subgraph have a Hamiltonian cycle?" is known to be difficult to answer: A. Itai, C. H. Papadimitriou, J. L. Szwarcfiter "Hamiltonian paths in grid graphs".
Unfortunately, there is not a neat description of the class of game ending subgraphs. I do not think all hope is lost for the question, maybe you can start by analyzing simpler games (stop when its disconnected, or stop when its 1-connected, etc...) to build intuition for this one.

Observation: color the graph like a chessboard. If any player moves on squares of the same color in a turn they lose immediately. The 2n by 2n grid is a bipartite graph with equal amounts of vertices of either color. If this symmetry is broken by any move then there is no way to make a Hamiltonian cycle
